# Replace Python List Elements with Odd Position with another value

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
l = ['3a' '4a' '5a' '6a' '7a' '4a' '4a' '5a' '6a' '7a' '4a']
```

and want to replace only elements with odd position in the list.
Result should be like:

```
res = ['xx' '4a' 'xx' '6a' 'xx' '4a' 'xx' '5a' 'xx' '7a' 'xx']
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried?

Comment: tried  l[0::2] = 'xx'

Comment: @patrickartner numpy arrays will print without commas. "Fake code" sounds a bit sensationalist.

Comment: @roganjosh   numpy arrays do not print as `l = [  '1'   '2'   '3' ]` - do they? - also: the OP speaks of `list`, tagged [tag:list] and not numpy - I am happy to remove my DV if he adjusts his question to something that is solveable.

Comment: but we don't know that it's a numpy array, because OP hasn't given any indication of that. In fact, OP has described the objects only as "list". If you `print` a numpy array, sure, but that's not what's being indicated in the body of this question.

Comment: the `res` assignment above, for example, produces this object: `['xx4axx6axx4axx5axx7axx']` and the `l` assignment: `['3a4a5a6a7a4a4a5a6a7a4a']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def replace_odd(l, v='xx'):
    return [v if not i%2 else x for i,x in enumerate(l)]
```

Answer (score 0):

By your example you want to replace the *even* elements, as in python the first element has the index 0.

Standard python:

```
l = ['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a', '7a', '4a', '4a', '5a', '6a', '7a', '4a']
for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
    l[i] = 'xx'
```

Using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array(['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a', '7a', '4a', '4a', '5a', '6a', '7a', '4a'])
l[::2] = 'xx'
```

Comment: Both examples are destructive to `l`, OP seems to want to get a new `res` list instead. Of course you can just create a copy beforehand, but it's nice to give a non-destructive example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `cycle` and `chain` from the `itertools` module.

```
from itertools import cycle, chain
l = ['3a', '4a', '5a', '6a', '7a', '4a', '4a', '5a', '6a', '7a', '4a']
print(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(l[1::2], cycle(['xx'])))))
```

This outputs:

```
['4a', 'xx', '6a', 'xx', '4a', 'xx', '5a', 'xx', '7a', 'xx']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print('Initial List with 10 Element:')
print(list)
for i in range(0, len(list), 2):
     list[i]=0
print('After replacing new element in the odd place:')
print(list)
list.append(16)
list.append(17)
list.append(18)
print('List after adding three element at the end')
print(list)
list.insert(0,100)
print('List after adding one element at the beginning:')
print(list)
list.extend([20,21,23,24,25])
print('List after adding new list to the existing one:')
print(list)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: **Try this one**